Failed to keep only last key (ordered) in Aerospike Map
I am trying to write facade code that always keep one (in this example, but maybe more keys but keep in desc by order) in a map in Aerospike.
Here is the facade code:
import com.aerospike.client.Value
import com.aerospike.client.cdt.MapOperation
import com.aerospike.client.cdt.MapOrder
import com.aerospike.client.cdt.MapPolicy
import com.aerospike.client.cdt.MapReturnType
import com.aerospike.client.cdt.MapWriteMode
import com.aerospike.client.query.KeyRecord
import com.aerospike.client.reactor.AerospikeReactorClient
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono

class ForStackOverflow(
    private val client: AerospikeReactorClient,
    private val keyResolver: KeyResolver
) {

    fun updateRuidVersion(key: String, version: Long, time: Long): Mono<KeyRecord> {
        val key = getKey(key)
        return client.operate(
            null,
            key,

            // Put this version with now time
            MapOperation.put(
                MapPolicy(MapOrder.KEY_ORDERED, MapWriteMode.UPDATE),
                RuidMetadataTablesSchema.LATEST_VERSION_BIN,
                Value.get(version),
                Value.get(time)
                ),
//            // keep only the latest version
            MapOperation.removeByRankRange(
                RuidMetadataTablesSchema.LATEST_VERSION_BIN,
                -2,1,
                MapReturnType.KEY
            )

        )


    }

    private fun getKey(key: String) =
        keyResolver.getKey(key)

}

Here is the test code that showes that it not deleting by rank - it deletes by last
@Test
fun `trying to keep only last version in table`(){
    val client = AerospikeReactorClientBuilder.getAerospikeReactorClient(config)
    val writerFacade = ForStackOverflow(
        client,
        simpleKeyResolver
    )
    val myId = "id-" + System.currentTimeMillis()
    val versions = (0..20).map {it}
    val allWrites = versions.reversed().map { version ->
        writerFacade.updateRuidVersion(
            myId, version.toLong(), System.currentTimeMillis()
        )
    }
    allWrites.forEach{
        it.block()
        val res = client.get(simpleKeyResolver.getKey(myId)).block()!!
        println(res.record.bins[RuidMetadataTablesSchema.LATEST_VERSION_BIN] as TreeMap<Long, Long>)
    }
}

and it prints the following:
{20=1716813009091}
{19=1716813009114}
{19=1716813009114}
{19=1716813009114}
{19=1716813009114}
{19=1716813009114}
{19=1716813009114}
{19=1716813009114}
{19=1716813009114}
{19=1716813009114}
{19=1716813009114}
{19=1716813009114}
{19=1716813009114}
{19=1716813009114}
{19=1716813009114}
{19=1716813009114}
{19=1716813009114}
{19=1716813009114}
{19=1716813009114}
{1=1716813009115}
{1=1716813009115}

I expected it to print only 20= always and not override it with old keys

Rank is by order of value (timestamp in your example) in the key-value pair. If value is same, rank is established by key order. Wondering if adding 1 ms sleep in the loop between each entry would give some clarity. i.e. make the timestamp values unique.
If I am following your code correctly (I reserve the right to be wrong! :-) ) - you insert 20:xx091, then 19:xx114, ( delete 2nd highest rank, deletes 20:xx091), then 18:xx114 (I am suspecting same timestamp value) - so deletes 18:xx114 (same value, then by key order) ... and so on. You were probably able to insert 18: thru 2: with xx114. Then 1:xx115, followed by 0:xx115.
So since we want to keep only the last Key and since the map is being ordered MapPolicy(MapOrder.KEY_ORDERED, MapWriteMode.UPDATE), then all you need to do is change the operation to removeByIndexRange
meaning it will look like this:
return client.operate(

            null,
            key,

            // Put this version with now time
            MapOperation.put(
                MapPolicy(MapOrder.KEY_ORDERED, MapWriteMode.UPDATE),
                RuidMetadataTablesSchema.LATEST_VERSION_BIN,
                Value.get(version),
                Value.get(time)
                ),
//            // keep only the latest version
            MapOperation.removeByIndexRange(
                RuidMetadataTablesSchema.LATEST_VERSION_BIN,
                -1,1,
                MapReturnType.INVERTED
            )

        )


Correct - but the answer is to just use removeByIndexRange

Very well then, you have a solution for what you were trying to achieve and what you were observing is also understood.

As mentioned before, the removeByRankRange is ordering the map by the value. In your case, where you want to trim the map based on the order of the keys (and your map is ordered), you might want to use removeByIndexRange.
For example:
Record record = client.operate(
        null,
        key,
        // Put this version with now time
        MapOperation.put(
                mapPolicy,
                binName,
                Value.get(version),
                Value.get(time)
        ),
        // keep only the latest (highest) version by map key
            MapOperation.removeByIndexRange(
                binName,
                -1, 1,
                MapReturnType.INVERTED
        ));


Great use of INVERTED flag - remove everything but -1, 1 (highest).
